# Why doesn't APFS come with the Journaled option?

Tags: mac, apfs, hfs+

A quick look in Disk Utility shows that Journaled is not an option with APFS like macOS Extended. Would anyone know why?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The main benefit you get from journaling is protection against metadata corruption in case of crashes (metadata like directory entries, file names, timestamps etc). APFS has a solution for this builtin, so there is no need to enable journaling specifically.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System):

> Apple File System is designed to avoid metadata corruption caused by system crashes. Instead of overwriting existing metadata records in place, it writes entirely new records, points to the new ones and then releases the old ones, an approach known as redirect-on-write. This avoids corrupted records containing partial old and partial new data caused by a crash that occurs during an update. It also avoids having to write the change twice, as happens with an HFS+ journaled file system, where changes are written first to the journal and then to the catalog file.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, [journals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) are "logs" what's about to be done to a file system. They are used to allow some crash protection to file systems which might get corrupted if a write operation is interrupted. For example, ext2 and HFS were vulnerable to these corruptions, so journaling was added which resulted in ext3 and HFS+.

[APFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System) on the other hand chose a design that doesn't need this protection. So there is no need for a journal. Likewise, [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) (which at one point was a candidate to replace HFS and has influenced APFS) doesn't need a journal by design, either.